# Android : How to make a widget take full screen in java

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I want to make a RelativeLayout that takes full screen in **JAVA CODE**.

Inside this RelativeLayout I want to have 2 ImaveView, one that is in the top-left side with 50 heigth and 50 weight and the other that is in the top-left side as well and that "match_parent".

For now I have that :

```
relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

    im = new ImageView(this);
    im.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50));

    im2 = new ImageView(this);
    im2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    im2.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    relativeLayout.addView(im2);
    relativeLayout.addView(im);
```

But the first image doesn't display and the second only take full weigth.

Here's an image of what I want :
[image]

Comment: If you want image1 to overlap image2 then Framelayout should be used.

Comment: @SagarPujari In XML I have RelativeLayout and it works juste fine, If I put my image 1 after my image 2 it works well. I just want to know how can I do the same thing in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this code ?

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);


        ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
        im.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
        im.setImageResource(R.color.accent);
        ImageView im2 = new ImageView(this);
        im2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        im2.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        im2.setImageResource(R.color.orderProcessing);
        relativeLayout.addView(im2);
        relativeLayout.addView(im);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Comment: thanks it works well, I tired and didn't see all the mistakes I made ^^'